# IDA Pro ignores present database with remote debugging

Tags: ida, gdb, remote

I have a qemu instance running a custom Linux distribution, within which I'd like to debug an (already running) application. I have already embedded a `gdbserver` inside (and have a root shell available), so I can start it with `--attach <pid>`. I also have extracted and analyzed the binary I am interested in and have an `.idb` file for it. However, when I connect to the remote GDB through IDA (via `Debugger > Attach to process`, and then selecting `0 - the running process`), it completely ignores everything in the database. No functions, no comments, nothing. ASLR is disabled, but if somehow still needed, I can provide `/proc/<pid>/maps`. The question is, how do I inform IDA that the app it's looking at is the same as the database?

If it matters, I'm running IDA Pro 7.5 on Windows